# Angular call function when JavaScript changed value of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using `angular` and I try to call my function `codeInputChanged()` every time the content of textarea get changed manually or by JavaScript code.

My `HTML` for my textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea class=code id="code" (input)="codeInputChanged()" (scroll)="scrollsync()">{{code}}</textarea>
```

I can call my function `codeInputChanged()` with `(input)= "codeInputChanged()"`. But this only works when I change the input of my textarea manually. Now I'm searching for a solution to call the function when the change is made by JavaScript code.

Comment: Why don't you just call codeInputChanged directly from your javascript code?

Comment: @user2263572 Calling the method directly from my javascript code is a bad solution in my opinion. I change the content of the variable ```code``` when I press a button in another component. And I don't think it's a good idea to also call the function from the other component.

Comment: The Angular documentation has an entire section devoted to component interactions.  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.  It's a major part of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call your function directly, such as

```
triggerInputChanged(){
    console.log('changing your input programatically');
    this.codeInputChanged();   
}
```

This should be pretty straightforward -- check my codepen showing this: https://codepen.io/OctavioSI/pen/KKpvBxV?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes,

```
<textarea class=code id="code" onchange="codeInputChanged()" (scroll)="scrollsync()">{{code}}</textarea>
```

OR

```
<textarea class=code id="code" (scroll)="scrollsync()" [ngModel]="data" (ngModelChange)="codeInputChanged()">{{code}}</textarea>
```